# How do I create local notification like push notification in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, notifications

I will use local notification, but I want to be able to change these notifications online when I want, how can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean online? You mean in run time or ? It would be nice to show us what you have done so far so we can try to help.

Comment: Firstly thank you for your answer :)
 My first build is have 3 different type local notification but later when I want to add new type notification, can I add the notification with on server or another things.
Example: 2 weeks later christmas so I want to sent new type notification.
It should work like this: Users have no internet so they have my standart notifications but they when connected the internet, I want to change their notification.
 I have low english :( I hope you could understand me

Answer (score 0):

You can use third party plugin like OneSignal or Firebase Cloud Message.... It help you can push notification whenever you want.

[Firebase Cloud Message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/)

[OneSignal](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Unity-SDK)